# Windows Service throwing Out of Memory exception after certain load

Tags: windows-services, out-of-memory

Am using windows service to publish my data to an API. Initially it worked fine in production  machine after installing. After some load is added the service threw Out Of Memory exception. We tried with same load in test machine and did not see any issue. 
Production Server is Windows 2012 R2, 64 GB RAM .

We can not get another chance of installing it on the production server.How can we find the exact root cause?

Comment: There is no magical solution here. You just have to debug your application. Start by catching and reporting all exceptions raised.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to some infinite loop in the code which caused it. It's better to test the business logic using the Nunit.